# Do something with each file in subdirectory according to size

Tags: bash

I'm getting started on a script and have this so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in $(find /home/username/ -maxdepth 1)
do
        if [[ $d == *.txt ]]
        then
                echo $d
        fi
done
```

This performs as expected, however I want it to give me the filenames according to their file size from largest to smallest.  I've found some answers for semi-related questions and saw some things like du and using find's printf option, but I haven't been able to cobble it all together yet.

Comment: Note that your code so far can be made both simpler and safer by just writing `find /home/username/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt'`, or even just `ls -1 /home/username/*.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find /home/username/ -name '*.txt' -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" |
sort -r -n -k1 |
cut -f2- |
while IFS= read -r file; do
   echo "$file"
done
```

- Print each file with it's size and filename
- numeric sort on the first column, ie. size
- remove the first column with cut
- read each line into `$line` variable
- `echo "$line"`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `stat` command to print each file along with its size, and then pipe to `sort`.

```
stat -f '%z %N' /home/username/*.txt | sort -nr
```

If you don't want to include the size in the output, you can then pipe to `cut`:

```
... | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
ls -1 -S /home/username/*.txt
```

where the `-1` flag tells `ls` to print one file per line, and the `-S` flag tells it to sort the files by size (from largest to smallest).

There are some minor differences between this and your code (for example, this won't list files whose names start with `.`), but I'm guessing that none of those differences are in things you care about. (If they *are*, please elaborate a bit about your requirements.)

Comment: `find` was your much better suggestion imho.  `find` can combine the name and the size and other components and control the output flexibly to support whatever the next step in the pipeline is.  Even if you don't need recursion it can often obviate further filtering.

Comment: `find` isn't necessary if you're not recursing. And it doesn't sort by size.

Comment: @DanFarrell: Just to make sure I understand: you're arguing that no one should ever use `ls`, because `find` is better for all purposes? In that case -- I respectfully disagree.

Comment: Your answer is fine and fwiw you have my vote.  I think it's fair to say that `find` is meant to, and has many good capabilities to , find files based on various of their attributes, and to completely control the formatting and the output of the results.  I want to encourage folks to look past `ls` when attempting to search for files given a number of known conditions.  I wanted somebody to include an example of find being used to filter the list of files effectively without addiotoinal steps, which, as you pointed out, is the power of `find`.